# Assert that a test failure is a success

Tags: c#, nunit, assert, assertions

In a nunit test, can we an assert that if the test fails at a certain circumstance then it is a pass (i.e. it is expected to try and fail).

But it should pass under all other circumstances.

Thing is that the test could fall apart before it can reach it's assertions sections.

I mean something in the lines of

```
[TestSetup]
void init()
{
    if (condition==true)
    {
    Assert.That(this test fails); /*any feature to do this?*/
    }
}
```

Comment: I really did not understand. Are you asserting something in the setup of the test? Maybe try to put your real example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the test can fail and it's classed as a pass under some circumstances, it sounds a bad test. Split it out into individual tests with clear method names detailing what it's achieving.

So instead of having one test and having a conditional inside it, split it out into each scenario. That way you can have the one scenario, where it is supposed to fail under something like

```
// do stuff
bool success = DoStuff();
Assert.IsFalse(success);
```

Comment: Agreed. Though your answer is not the exact one I was looking for, still I think it is better than what I am looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to understand your question. Are you wanting [`Assert.Fail()`](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=utilityAsserts&r=2.2.7) to force a failure? Like so...

```
[TestSetup]
public void Init()
{
    if (condition==true)
    {
    Assert.Fail();
    }
}
```

If instead you want to *check* for failure instead of *cause* one, you should follow Arran's advice and check for a specific fact about the work you're validating - such as a method's return value.

Comment: I was looking for something like assert that it fails and not cause a failure. Anyway I think my plan of action was based upon a shaky foundation and possibly Arran's suggestion (check the ans above) is best. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the "Action" object to invoke the code in an action and test that action if it is an exception. Look at FluentAssertions they have lots of examples.

```
    int number1 = 1;
    int number0 = 0;
    Action someAction = () => { int j = number1 / number0; };
    someAction.ShouldThrow<DivideByZeroException>();
```